# Cast from 'JSON' to unrelated type 'String' always fails

Tags: ios, swift

Currently I'm using `SwiftyJSON` to convert the data set into JSON type.

When I run this: `print(json)`, it will print on the Xcode console.

```
{
  "user_id": "123999923821" 
}
```

But whenever I try to do execute `json["user_id"] as? String`, it always returns nil.

```
socketManager.socket.on("toAllDrivers") { data, ack in
            if let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PopViewControllerID") as? PopUpViewController {

                let json = JSON(data[0])
                print(json)
                vc.passenger_id = json["user_id"] as? String // This is the line of code that return a problem.

                self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }


        }
```

`vc.passenger_id` is a type String:

```
var passenger_id: String?
```

The error is:

> Cast from 'JSON' to unrelated type 'String' always fails

What should I do to fix this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should use `SwiftyJSON`'s built in String converter to convert the value to an optional `String`.

```
vc.passenger_id = json["user_id"].string
```

Comment: In case of **user_id** is nil, How to handle it? I mean, How to apply if let here?

Comment: The resulting variable is an optional String - you can handle it as you would always handle a String?

Answer (score 2):

Try this: (without using SwiftyJSON and it should work)

```
if let json = JSON(data[0]) as? [String : Any] {
   vc.passenger_id = json["user_id"] as? String
}
```

or

```
if let user_id = json["user_id"] as? String {
   vc.passenger_id = user_id
   print("user_id- \(user_id)")
}
print("vc.passenger_id - \(vc.passenger_id)")
```